# Telegrap API (not bot api), listing all service messages in a chat

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I am using telegram API messages.getHistory (see [here](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory) and [here](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/client/messages.py#L25)). I successfully get normal messages, but it does not return serviceMessages (such as user X joined).

The API doc is not very good. I am wondering if something needs to be set for getHistory to include service messages.

My goal is to get the list of all service messages and delete them from the chat.

Answer (score 0):

you can read this section: [Working with Updates](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/basic/working-with-updates.html) and use `events.ChatAction`

for example :

```
import logging


from telethon import TelegramClient, events

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

api_id = XXXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+989XXXXX'

################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash
                    )


@client.on(events.ChatAction(chats=(-1001300989485')))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    pass # Do something for example (await event.delete())


client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()

print('finish')
```

With this code everyone joining the group or leaving the group you will understand